# Scapy Installation error in CentOS release 6.9 server?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, scapy

I am trying to install scapy in server. But I am getting error.
1) I installed pip, python 2.66 was already installed.
2) Then i ran command pip installed scapy

Then in the terminal when i type scapy, i get:

```
[root@virgina02 alamin]# scapy
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
INFO: No IPv6 support in kernel
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
INFO: Can't import python Crypto lib. Won't be able to decrypt WEP.
INFO: Can't import python Crypto lib. Disabled certificate manipulation tools
INFO: Can't import python ecdsa lib. Disabled certificate manipulation tools
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in __subclasscheck__' in <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> ignored
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
>>
```

now I can still use scapy to send tcp packets but I am getting checksum error. So I was wondering if that checksum error was related to the above error?

Answer (score 0):

This warning did not cause the checksum error. The checksum error was my mistake.
I also found why I got this error.

This error/warnings ware due to python2.6.
Scapy higher version of 2 requires python >= 2.7

Answer (score -1):

try `sudo python` that might work.

For detailed info, [see](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/issues/49)